# Remove data from String using Regex

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
"Event: {\"resource\":\"/api/v1/tokens\",\"path\":\"/api/v1/tokens\",\"httpMethod\":\"POST\",\"headers\":{\"Version\":\"HTTP/1.1\",\"User-Agent\":\"PostmanRuntime/7.19.0\",\"Accept\":\"*/*\",\"Postman-Token\":\"4d728c40-a6f8-46fa-9131-2bff7a2c5b69\",\"Host\":\"localhost:8888\",\"Accept-Encoding\":\"gzip, deflate\",\"Connection\":\"keep-alive\",\"cache-control\":\"no-cache\",\"content-type\":\"application/json\"},\"queryStringParameters\":{},\"pathParameters\":null,\"stageVariables\":null,\"requestContext\":{},\"body\":\"{\\n\\t\\\"client_id\\\": \\\"6dd930eb-e4dc-48d9-a18b-ace0c7406234\\\",\\n\\t\\\"secure_client_secret\\\": \\\"fedfc0a7-af1e-413c-ab51-1955113b2b69\\\"\\n}\",\"isBase64Encoded\":false}"
```

Is there a way to filter out all keys and values with `secure`prefix:

```
"secure_client_secret\\\": \\\"fedfc0a7-af1e-413c-ab51-1955113b2b69\\\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `"secure[^:]+:\s*"[^"]+"`

Explanation:

`"secure` - match `"secure` lietrally

`[^:]+` - match one or more characters other from `:`

`:` - match `:`

`\s*` - match zero or more whitespaces

`"[^"]+"` - match `"`, one or more characters other from `"` and then match `"`